# PHP and HTML: acquire all GET-values

Tags: php, html, get

I am in need of a PHP-program which will take all values from a HTML-link (with GET), regardless of how much one changes things in the address-bar, and then prints it out on the page. The code I have now is this:

HTML:

```
<a href="test.php?a=value1&amp;b=value2& amp;c=value3">Link</a>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 

Echo "Value1: "; Echo $_GET["a"]; Echo "\n";
Echo "Value2: "; Echo $_GET["b"]; Echo "\n";
Echo "Value3: "; Echo $_GET ["c"];

?>
```

It works as intended for just these values, but it cannot cope with, for example, another variable being added in the address bar. I need some kind of PHP-function which can look for all kinds of variables through the GET-function.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `foreach ($_GET as $key => $variable)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop (modify as needed):

```
foreach ($_GET as $num => $value)
{
    echo 'Value ' . $num . ': ' . htmlentities($value). "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

References:

- [Control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php)
- [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Answer (score 1):

you get all $_GET values using print_r($GET) ...

otherwise you could to something like this

```
foreach(array_keys($_GET) as $key) {

echo htmlspecialchars($_GET[$key]);

}
```

***Later Edit : took into account the security issue exposed in the comment***

using this method is good because you know what kind of variable you have then you could do something cool like :

```
if ($key == 'a') do this
if ($key == 'b' && $_GET[$key] == 'bar') do that
```

Comment: i agree , but I think op should do whatever he wants with the variables

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
  echo htmlspecialchars($key) . " - " . htmlspecialchars($value) . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    print_r($_GET);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a foreach loop

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $val){
  echo htmlentities($key).": ".htmlentities($val)."<br />\n";
 }
```

or simply -

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($_GET,1)."</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all values and their corresponding names:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
{
     echo $key . ' - ' . $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$my_get = array(); // store $_GET vars

if ('GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) // check that request method is "get"
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $val)
    {
        $my_get[$key] = $val; // store
    }
```

output $my_get:

```
array (
  'a' => 'value1',
  'b' => 'value2',
  'c' => 'value3',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since $_GET is nothing but an array, you can use for each loop to get the elements of it.